# Existe algum emulador de iOS para testar uma aplicação desenvolvida no Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, emulador

Não há nada como testar no dispositivo real, porém em alguns casos os emuladores são extremamente necessários. Para o Android eu utilizo o Genymotion, mas no momento preciso de algum emulador de iOS que para que possa testar a compatibilidade básica de um aplicativo desenvolvido no Xamarin.

Existe algum emulador de iOS que não precise de um dispositivo real e rode no Windows ou Linux?

Neste caso estou utilizando o Visual Studio e Xamarin, as outras perguntas que foram relacionadas a esta se referem ao Ionic/Cordova.

Comment: Quase certeza que não. Outro detalhe, provavelmente já dever saber, mas sem um mac nao vai ter como mandar pra loja (app store).

Comment: Sim, pois é necessário "assinar" os binários depois. O problema é que para um desenvolvimento em uma equipe onde há somente um disponível, dificulta o processo de testes, por isso pensei na questão do emulador.

Comment: Sei bem o seu problema. Eu penso assim: Que o iPhone é um Mac em miniatura, então do mesmo jeito que é difícil usar o OSX fora de um Mac, vai ser tao difícil quanto, senão mais até, de fazer o simulador funcionar fora do Mac. Mas se encontrar algo da um toque que também acharia bem util.

Comment: http://www.itrickbuzz.com/iphone-ipad-ios-emulator-for-windows-pc/

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/testflight/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe algum emulador de iOS que não precise de um dispositivo real e rode no Windows ou Linux?

Não.

---

Algumas alternativas:

- Utilizar um ambiente de virtualização (VMWare ou algo do tipo) e criar uma VM com macOS.
  Com tudo, você vai criar uma VM para rodar um emulador (que em termos macros também é uma VM)... A não ser que você tenha um computador muito bom, é bem provável que a máquina ficará lenta;
- Conectar o VisualStudio (Windows) á uma máquina com macOS via rede;
- Por último, você pode usar o [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud) que é um grande repositório de dispositos **reais/físicos** e que simula todos os movimentos possíveis da iteração humana com o dispositivo. É como se tivesse alguém tocando a tela do celular. Você pode escolher o aparelho e escrever algo semelhante a um `Test Case` e pedir para o Test Cloud rodar.
  Com tudo, esse é um recurso (bem) caro.

Se você vai produzir aplicações Xamarin para iPhone de forma profissional, aconselho fortemente a adquirir um Mac.

---

Detalhe: o ponto que citei no segundo *bullet* é "judicialmente legal" se a relação for 1 para 1. Você não pode ter um único Mac e conectar vários desenvolvedores com Windows nele. Você só pode (legalmente falando) conectar **um** Windows á **um** Mac para propósitos de desenvolvimento.

Não é que não é possível conectar mais de uma pessoa. Só não é "judicialmente legal".

Answer (score 1):

Se você possui um MAC , no visual studio existe um Simulador que espelha o emulador do seu MAC. Não existe forma de compilar um app do iOs sem mac.

Se você possui um mac, no visual studio vá em Tools/ Options/ Xamarin /iOs Settings , vai ter um checkbox para utilizar o simulador.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Boa notícia, existe:

[Remoted iOS Simulator (for Windows)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Má notícia 1, infelizmente isso não te livra de ter um `MAC` ou ter que virtualizar um.
Má notícia 2 `Remoted iOS Simulator requires a Visual Studio Enterprise license`
=/

> Fonte:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/

Comment: Não adianta muito essa solução, pois precisa ter um mac, se tens um mac, não precisa de um emulador. basta usar o mac de uma vez. 

Estava procurando uma solução, mas realmente, a Apple te força a comprar o mac, não tem jeito.

Comment: @ClaudionorOliveira exatamente, mas na pergunta o usuário da pergunta tem o MAC. No seu caso sugiro um máquina virtual, eu utilizava uma até bem pouco tempo (maquina separada do ambiente de desenvolvimento) e supriu minhas necessidades, boa sorte.

Comment: boa sugestão, uma maquina virtual parece ser uma boa saída.